# "I got my bluff called on that" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

It is a dialogue from a series I need to translate. It goes:

-Your mom says your dad checked out okay by the way. I figured you'd wanna know.

-If you had asked me this morning, I would have said I didn't care how he turned out. But I got my bluff called on that one today.

-He's your dad. Of course, you care.

Can you paraphrase "I got my bluff called on that"? What is he exactly saying?

Comment: Ellie, google: "to call one's bluff!"

Comment: I did, but still can't paraphrase it and get the actual meaning in this context.

Comment: It's a slightly "quirky / facetious" reversal of phrasing. Most native speakers would more naturally say ***They called my bluff** on that*. It's basically a metaphoric extension from "bluffing" in betting card games like poker (ptetending that you hold better cards than you actually have), where if an opponent "calls your bluff", you lose your stake.

Comment: Possible paraphrase using another idiom: *But those words would have **sounded hollow** today*.

Comment: This is the second time today that you have quoted a dialogue without indication its source.  I have downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

The logic is that if he were bluffing when he said that he did not care how his father turned out, and his bluff were "called" on that statement, one or more persons had uncovered the reality that he *did* actually care.  Saying he did not care may have been a failed attempt at hiding his true feelings--but, since his bluff was called on this, the feelings were made apparent and he was unable to conceal them in the end.  Now (later than "this morning"), he is admitting that he would no longer say that he did not care.

Comment: I don't think there are any other people involved. Some impersonal force (Nature/Fate/Chance/God/the World) has called his bluff by making something bad happen to his dad.

Comment: @Evene The situation began with something happening to his dad, and it was _after_ this that he was willing to say he did not care how he turned out.  Something then occurred still later to reverse his attitude.  It seems illogical for that something to be yet another problem with his dad.

Comment: you could be right. Context is everything. I read that conversation as saying this morning his (possibly estranged?) dad was fine, and the during the day something happened to him.